# Which time control was set in the following game?

Tags: time-control

[Event "Russia vs China"]
[Site "Sochi RUS"]
[Date "2009.08.17"]
[EventDate "2009.08.15"]
[Round "3"]
[Result "1-0"]
[White "Ding Liren"]
[Black "Nikita Vitiugov"]
[ECO "D45"]
[WhiteElo "2530"]
[BlackElo "2681"]
[PlyCount "81"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. Nf3 d5 3. c4 e6 4. Nc3 c6 5. e3 Nbd7 6. Qc2 Bd6 7. g4 h6 8. h3 a6 9. c5 Be7 10. Rg1 b6 11. cxb6 Qxb6 12. g5 hxg5 13. Nxg5 Rg8 14. Na4 Qa7 15. Qxc6 Bb7 16. Qc2 Rc8 17. Nc3 e5 18. Bd2 exd4 19. exd4 Qxd4 20. Be3 Qb4 21. O-O-O Nc5 22. f3 Bc6 23. Bd4 a5 24. Rg2 a4 25. Re2 Rc7 26. Be5 Rd7 27. Rd4 Qb6 28. h4 a3 29. b3 Rb7 30. Bh3 Rh8 31. b4 Ncd7 32. Na4 Qb5 33. Bd6 Ng8 34. Nc3 Qb6 35. Qf5 Kd8 36. Nxf7+ Kc8 37. Bc5 Nh6 38. Bxb6 Nxf5 39. Bxf5 Bf6 40. Nxd5 Kb8 41. Nxf6 1-0

Which time control was set in this game ?

Answer (score 2):

I've looked all over the web and cannot find the specific time control used, but according to many sources I found via Google, this game was the 3rd round of the classical portion of the annual Russia vs China match, so definitely NOT a rapid/blitz game. I believe in recent years the classical time control for that event has been 40 moves in 90 minutes (relatively quick for that level).